# how do we set menu list globally

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Initially I have to attach with each action :-

Here we first fetch menu detail then pass in to view section.

```
Class ManageadministratorController extends Controller {
    public $data_menu;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $obj = new General;
        $this->data_menu=$obj->displaymenu();
    }
   public function index()
   {     
     $obj = new General;
     $permission = $obj->checkViewPermission("manageadministrator"); 
     $query= Adminlogin::get();
     return View::Make('admin.manageadministrator.manage',array('record'=>$query,'menu_list'=>$this->data_menu));    
   }
   function add()
   {
      return View::Make('admin.manageadministrator.add',array('menu_list'=>$this->data_menu)); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Use provider. See http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers for more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a custom service provider or use AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
{
    $obj = new General;
    $data_menu = $obj->displaymenu();
    view()->composer('admin.manageadministrator', function($view) {
        $view->with('menu_list', $data_menu);
    });
}
```

Or use a dedicated class:

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('admin.manageadministrator', 'App\Http\Composers\MasterComposer');
}



// app/Http/Composers/MasterComposer.php
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class MasterComposer {

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $obj = new General;
        $data_menu = $obj->displaymenu();
        $view->with('menu_list', $data_menu);
    }
}
```

Comment: I put this code on AppServiceProvider.php   public function boot()
{
    $obj = new General;
    $data_menu = $obj->displaymenu();
    view()->composer('admin.manageadministrator', function($view) {
        $view->with('menu_list', $data_menu);
    });
}   it gives undefine datamenu in manage administrator